# Devise New Route and Form Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I have a standard devise user registration form with name and email. I want to create another form to get more info from the user on another page and input the new field into the user model. I created the migrations for new field in the user model.

I created the route in a devise loop, the method in the controller and created a view page with the form. The route below works, the form shows up on the page but when i click submit, nothing happens. I wanted to confirm if my route and form code is correct.

routes.rb -  do I need a 'put' or 'post' below??

```
 devise_scope :users do 
   put '/users/bankacc', :to => 'application#bankacc' 
end
```

my view code - do I need a form_for or a form_tag in this case?

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: users_bankacc_path, html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
    #form inputs
<% end %>
```

In my method - how do I find the ActiveRecord? When I enter `User.find(params[:id])` it says user not found.

Comment: check your `params[:id]` has a correct value, and if you don't want exception for `nil` value or wrong value for `params[:id]` use `User.where(id: params[:id])`

Comment: Is the id being passed through? Is the form_for the right command to use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You use this form for edit/new user, so you need to check on the action post(for new_record)/put(update exists record), so use the following code:

```
- url = @user.new_record? ? users_bankacc_path : users_bankacc_path(@user)
- method = @user.new_record? ? "post" : "put"
<%= form_for(@user, url: url, html: { method: method.to_sym }) do |f| %>
  #form inputs
<% end %>
```

You need to update your routes as the following:

```
put '/users/bankacc', :to => 'application#bankacc', :as => 'users_bankacc'
```

Comment: the first two lines to check on the instance variable `@user` if it is a new_record then go to the create path with post method, else go to the update action with the put method

Comment: This form will always be filled by existing users. does the above still apply?

Comment: try to update your routes as `put '/users/bankacc', :to => 'application#bankacc', :as => 'users_bankacc'`

Comment: users_bankacc is the path it creates anyway. So why do I need to do that? I'm trying to understand the code.

Comment: sometimes if you don't put `as:` in routes, and run this command `rake routes`, you may not see this link in `Prefix` column.